# Converting line height to lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier

Tags: android, textview

If I want to display text with, say, a font size of `20sp` and a line height<sup>*</sup> of `30sp`, how would I express that in terms of `lineSpacingExtra` and/or `lineSpacingMultiplier`?

It seems that neither `lineSpacingExtra="10sp"` nor `lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"` looks quite right.

[*] With line height behaving as it does in CSS, in Illustrator, or in most layout design tools.

Comment: If you set a `TextView` font size to `20sp` and call `getLineHeight()` on it, does that give you something to work with? It returns in pixels, so you'll have to convert to sp if that's what you want to work with.

Comment: I think the first logical answer would be `lineSpacingExtra="10sp"` and no `lineSpacingMultiplier`. However in this case, we considered the font to have a height of `20sp` which most probably is false.